# Does strlen() always correctly report the number of char's in a pointer initialized string?

Tags: c, strlen

As long as I use the `char` and not some `wchar_t` type to declare a string will `strlen()` correctly report the number of `char`s in the string or are there some very specific cases I need to be aware of? Here is an example:

```
char *something = "Report all my chars, please!";
strlen(something);
```

Comment: Be aware of non-null-terminated strings...  (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631516/strlen-on-non-null-terminated-char-string)

Comment: `"This would \0 go wrong"`

Comment: @G.Rassovsky: That wouldn't be a "string", would it.

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Are you debugging some issue and suspect that `strlen` does not operate correctly?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe, no. :) The program which uses `strlen()` does it's job perfect. I just wanted to catch any possible corner cases.

Comment: As long as there are no embedded zeros, e.g. from a non-ASCII character set and you haven't let the string go out of scope or accidentally corrupted its memory then yes you're fine.

Comment: @AndyBrown No edge cases, like where you're trying to read a string outside your allocated memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What `strlen` does is basically count all bytes until it hits a zero-byte, the so-called null-terminator, character `'\0'`.

So as long as the string contains a terminator within the bounds of the memory allocated for the string, `strlen` will correctly return the number of `char` in the string.

Note that `strlen` can't count the number of characters (code points) in a multi-byte encoded string (like UTF-8). It will correctly return the number of bytes in the string though.