# C - strcpy() function restrictions

Tags: c

I am incredibly new in C programming and I'm having a hard time understanding some aspects of it, including the `strcpy()` function.

I am doing some quizzes and passed over the following question:

To assure the correctness of the following `strcpy(d,s)` call, which of the following conditions must always be met:

a. sizeof(d) >= strlen(s) + 1

b. sizeof(d) >= sizeof(s)

c. sizeof(d) >= strlen(s)

d. strlen(d) >= strlen(s)

e. strlen(d) >= strlen(s) + 1

After doing some research, I found that the size of the destination string should be large enough to store the copied string. [Source here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/string.h/strcpy). This led me to answers either b or d.

However the correct answer is 'a' and I cannot understand why, and cannot find any documentation. Could someone please explain in more details what the restrictions of `strcpy()` are?

Comment: how are `d` and `s` declared, are they both static arrays or are they pointers? `sizeof` does not work the same for static and dynamic arrays (e.g `int a[20]` and `int* a`)

Comment: @Chase, unfortunately I do not have this information. This is all the information that was given to me in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sort of depends on how the variables are declared and/or defined even, however judging by the fact that the answer is `a`, I'm positive that this is how they were declared and defined-

```c
// Assume SIZE_0 and SIZE_1 are some integer values
char d[SIZE_0];
char s[SIZE_1];

// Assign a bunch of characters to `s` here and null terminate it
// Assume `s` now has `LEN` number of characters + 1 for the null terminator, for a total of `LEN + 1`
// Of course, `LEN + 1` is either less than, or equal to, `SIZE_1`
```

Now let's get the values cleared up real quick-

- `strlen(s)` -> Returns `LEN`, as it counts the number of characters until the null terminator
- `sizeof(s)` -> Returns `SIZE_1`
- `sizeof(d)` -> Returns `SIZE_0`
- `strlen(d)` -> Doesn't work as you'd think, `strlen` won't work without a null terminator, currently `d` has no value - so there's no length, not even `0` would count unless you set `d[0]` to `'\0'` by yourself

So, it's evident that for `strcpy(d, s)` to work, `sizeof(d)` (which is the only valid call) MUST BE more than, or equal to, `LEN + 1` (`LEN` for all the characters from `s` and +1 for the null terminator).

Of course, `strlen` on `s` will return `LEN`, so we'll need `strlen(s) + 1`.

And *that* is why you need `sizeof(d)` to be more than, or equal to, `strlen(s) + 1`.

I must say though, if `strlen` did return the *capacity* (aka `size`) of the string, instead of the *current length*, your assumption would work.

At the end of the day, always remember the difference between **capacity** (`size`) and **length**, especially in C.

Comment: So we are going under the assumption that d would have no value assigned to it when strcpy(d,s) is being called? Is the null terminator mandatory when assigning values to these variables? Meaning, what if s did not have the null terminator?

Comment: @ElenaM. yep! because if `d` has a null terminated string assigned to it, option c would be correct as well, since then `strlen` is a valid call.

Comment: I should also mention, option B is also correct (assigned or not), but that's really pushing it as that's not the *minimum boundary*

Comment: Asking again as you might not see my edit. 
Is the null terminator mandatory when assigning values to these variables? Meaning, what if s did not have the null terminator?

Comment: @ElenaM. C strings should always be null terminated, otherwise you're going towards undefined behaviour territory, library functions like `strlen` will not work on non-null terminated strings, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/631516/strlen-on-non-null-terminated-char-string)

Comment: Alright! That really cleared things up. Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 0):

All character strings in `C` (the kind used by functions such as `strcpy`) must have a nul-terminator (a zero-value `char` signalling the end of the string). So, to store a string like `"abc"`, you will need any `char[]` array to have *at least four* elements: one for each of the letters plus one for the `nul`-terminator.

The [`strlen()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) function returns the number of characters in the given string *not including* that `nul`-terminator; but the [`strcpy()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) function copies all characters *including* the terminator, so the destination buffer must be at least one 'char`greater than the`strlen` of the source.

Also note that the `sizeof(d)` calculation will *only* work if `d` is declared as an *array* of `char` (e.g. `char d[42]`); if that array is passed to a function, it will 'decay' to a pointer, and the array's size will not be (implicitly) known to that function; see this discussion: [How to find the 'sizeof' (a pointer pointing to an array)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeof-a-pointer-pointing-to-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

It is copying a sequence of character bytes with a null terminator. For example the string "ABC" is represented 65,66,67,0.

strlen calculates the length of the string excluding the null terminator (e.g. 3 for "ABC"). sizeof (for an array) gives you the amount of memory set aside for the array. The string it contains may be shorter.

char s[20] = "ABC";   would give you a string of length 3, using 4 bytes including the terminator, in a reserved memory space of 20 bytes.

To safely copy from s to d, you need to have enough space in d to receive the string and its terminator (without the terminator you won't have a valid string). Hence strlen(s)+1.

The size of s is irrelevant as not all of the reserved space will be copied. strlen(d) is irrelevant also - any existing string in d will be overwritten.

So option a is correct.